# If $a \gt 2$ and $b=1+ \sqrt{a-1}$ then $2 \lt b \lt a$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $a,b \in R$. Prove that if $a \gt 2$ and $b=1+ \sqrt{a-1}$ then $2 \lt b \lt a$.

Explanation: I know I start by breaking the conclusion into two parts when I'm thinking about it. So, when I'm trying to solve $2 \lt b$ I start by assuming $2-b = 2 - (1 + \sqrt{a-1})$, since $a \gt 2$, $2 \lt b$.

However, when I try to solve for $b \lt a$, I get $b - a = 1 + \sqrt{a-1} - a$. Once manipulate the equation a little I end up with $b - a = \sqrt{a-1}(1-\sqrt{a-1})$.

I get here and I don't know what is safe to assume. Am I missing a basic concept that will help me move forward?

Comment: Did you try isolating $\sqrt{a-1}$ on one side of the desired inequality, and then squaring? (You do, of course, need to be a little careful when squaring an inequality …)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a>2 \implies \sqrt{a-1}>1 \implies 1+\sqrt{a-1}>2 \implies b>2$

also, $a-b=a-1-\sqrt{a-1}=\sqrt{a-1}(\sqrt{a-1}-1)>0$ as $a>2 \implies \sqrt{a-1}>1$

putting both together we have, $2<b<a$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact, that for any $x > 1$ the following holds:

$\sqrt{x}< x$

Answer (score 0):

Key idea: Given $x\in R\quad x^2>1$ if and only if $x>1$

$a>2\\
\to a-1>1$

$\sqrt{a-1}>1$ but $b-1=\sqrt{a-1}$

hence $b-1>1$ and $b>2$

$b-1=\sqrt{a-1}\\
\to b^2-2b+1=a-1\\
\to b^2-3b+2=a-b\\
\to (b-2)(b-1)=a-b$

$b-2>0$ and $b-1>0$ so their product is positive.

$a-b>0\\
\to a>b$

Thus we see $a>b>2$ so $2<b<a$.

This is what needed to be proven.